# Convert time-stamp in to seconds since Unix epoch

Tags: java, timestamp

How to convert time-stamp in to seconds since Unix epoch?
I just convert time-stamp into UTC time-stamp. Now i want to convert this time-stamp into seconds.

```
Calendar currenttime = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("current: "+currenttime.getTime());

    //TIMESTAMP UTC/GMT
    TimeZone z = currenttime.getTimeZone();
    int offset = z.getRawOffset();
    if(z.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
        offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
    }
    int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
    int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;
    currenttime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
    currenttime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));
    System.out.println("GMT CURRENT TIME: "+currenttime);
```

Answer (score 1):

see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)

It says Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

As per you code

```
currenttime.getTime().getTime() / 1000

Calendar currenttime = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("current: "+currenttime.getTime());

//TIMESTAMP UTC/GMT
TimeZone z = currenttime.getTimeZone();
int offset = z.getRawOffset();
if(z.inDaylightTime(new Date())){
    offset = offset + z.getDSTSavings();
}
int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;
currenttime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (-offsetHrs));
currenttime.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (-offsetMins));
System.out.println("GMT CURRENT TIME: "+currenttime);
```

with the addition of

```
System.out.println("This is : " + currenttime.getTime().getTime() / 1000 + " seconds");
```

Comment: Can you please expand/explain it more??

Comment: Thnks for reply.
I try this but its shows error like "The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) Date, int".

Comment: Hey sorry once agn but still its not working properly
now its says"The method getTime() is undefined for the type GetCurrentTimeStamp"

Comment: In that case your code does not match the above, as the above is using   a Calendar object as currenttime.  see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide Java millis by 1000